# Comparação de matriz e vetor C/C++

Tags: c, array, c++, vector

Preciso comparar um vetor op inserido pelo usuário com as 10 primeiras colunas de cada linha de uma matriz 12x12.

```
for(k=0; k<10; k++){
for(i=0; i<12; i++){
    for(j=0; j<10; j++){
        if(op[k]==d[i][j]){
            if(i==1)
                flagd1++;
            if(i==2)
                flagd2++;
            if(i==3)
                flagd3++;
            if(i==4)
                flagd4++;
            if(i==5)
                flagd5++;
            if(i==6)
                flagd6++;
            if(i==7)
                flagd7++;
            if(i==8)
                flagd8++;
            if(i==9)
                flagd9++;
            if(i==10)
                flagd10++;
            if(i==11)
                flagd11++;
            if(i==12)
                flagd12++;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: No seu código você está comparando por cada casa do vetor a matriz em linha i (12) e coluna/casas j (10). As flags você esta colocando conforme o número da linha, se a linha for a 1 o flagd1 será incrementado em 1. Não entendi muito bem o que deseja, seu código condiz com o que quer. Vi somente um errinho aqui: if(i==10) flagd11++;

Comment: oque você quer fazer nesse flag?

Comment: Esse padrão de vários ifs num `for` com base no `i` está sempre errado. Imagine que não eram `10` casas mas sim `100`, ia fazer `100` ifs ? A ideia de utilizar `fors` é precisamente poder automatizar esse tipo de coisas

Comment: @Forsaiken Estou fazendo um score, é um código para identificar o vetor op informado pelo usuário e compara-lo com uma matriz já definida. "No seu código você está comparando por cada casa do vetor a matriz em linha i (12) e coluna/casas j (10). As flags você esta colocando conforme o número da linha, se a linha for a 1 o flagd1 será incrementado em 1.". É exatamente isso que eu desejo.

Comment: @Isac,sim, porém é uma matriz de 12x12 sendo que a ultima coluna será usada para guardar os flags e a penultima será enumerda de 1 a 12 para a idenficação posterior. Tem alguma sugestão para mudar o a forma que faço isso?

Comment: @FelipeRezende Só vendo como são utilizadas as flags é que poderia dar uma sugestão de como resolver